# Finding Java path in windows 8

Tags: windows, java

Can any help me find the Java path in windows 8? I am trying to get it through my firewal but it wont work.

I have found C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin but not sure it is correct.

Comment: JavaScript != Java. Please use the correct tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default java location will

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\javac"

and but the above won't be same in all the machines. you can use the below command in cmd and fetch the installation path.

> c:> for %i in (java.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i

Comment: `for %i in (java.exe) do @echo. %~$PATH:i` returns a symlink to the real java.exe (on my machine at least). I'm not sure you can use a symlink to add firewall rules ...